# How to send variables between functions in a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I just started building a Chrome extension, but I'm not sure how everything works. 
I want to get a string of data in one method (getTabs) and then return it to the method that called it. 
This code calls getTabs which creates a string and tries to return it.

```
function emailTabs() {  
chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(null, getTabs);
console.log(data); //this is never able to access the string
}

function getTabs(tabs) {
  var data='';
  //build up data... 
  console.log(data); //this works when there's no anonymous function
  return data;
}
```

How do I get that string back in the emailTabs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `getTabs` return something, you can create an anonymous function in getAllInWindow to gain more control over it, then catch the value with something like this :

```
function emailTabs() {
    chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(null, function(tabs){
        var str = getTabs(tabs);
        // some code using the string
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I try accessing data, it just shows up as "Object object", so it's still not getting the value.

Comment: I updated my answer, basically you need the function "getTabs" to return something first, then you will be able to catch and assign the value in the getAllInWindow callback (second parameter)

Comment: Thanks. It still doesn't work exactly since when I change it to an anonymous function getTabs ends up not getting the tabs that it needs from getAllInWindow. I'll figure something out though.

Comment: you need to give getTabs all the parameters it expects, then it will work exactly as if you called "getTabs" directly, I hope this solves your issue

Comment: Oh, I see, I need to pass in the parameter into the anonymous function and then into getTabs. Now it works. Thanks!

Comment: I wish Google had explained that more clearly on their tutorials page.